# How to set .jar entry point class that is located in other package

Tags: java, jar

I'm using Windows 10. Currently trying to figure out how to work with java files from the console. Bumped into a problem - I have 3 **.java** files and **.\bin** directory where all my **.class** files are stored. I want to create a **.jar** file, put all **.class** files in it and make **.\bin\Test1.class** file an entry point for this archive

So I tried this command that I found on Oracle docs

```
jar cfe app.jar bin/Test1 bin/*.class
```

It worked and I got everything I need in this archive but when I try to run the application by

```
java -jar app.jar
```

the error appears and tells that It could not find the main class
[Error text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YH7wU.png)

So I tried using different delimiters in command and manifest file, added **Class-Path:** attribute in manifest (however not sure what exactly should be in it), tried running from administrator. Nothing works

Comment: I guess there is no `bin` folder in your jar. remove it

Comment: *and make .\bin\Test1.class file an entry point for this archive* You don't want to do that. If you do that, you would have to put Test1 in package 'bin' `jar cfe app.jar Test1 -C bin *.class` is the command you actually need

Comment: So I guess I can't have entry point in package which is located in that same archive. Is it always like that or maybe I can somehow specify the path for this entry point (for example in manifest)?